# How do I consistently rip my DVDs to ISOs in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, dvd, iso-image, ripping

I'm trying to backup all of my DVDs to ISO files. I've been using [ISORecorder](http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/isorecorder.htm) but there are several DVDs that I'm unable to copy (e.g. 'Romeo + Juliet', 'Gladiator', etc.) The problem, I think, has to do with these discs having some sort of copy protection on them; using ISORecorder doesn't produce the desired effect.

Is there a program/process by which I can bypass some of these 'features' to rip my DVDs to ISOs? If not, is there a file format by which I can convert my DVDs to that will retain all of the features and that can be easily converted back to a DVD disc format?

Comment: You are asking to break copy protection? Probably won't be answered here.

Comment: It's been discussed on meta: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2212/is-discussion-of-techniques-for-removing-drm-permitted. I'm asking how to legitimately backup media that I've purchased. DRM laws are not the same everywhere so, not talking about the morality of backing up withstanding, this is not necessarily an illegal enterprise.

Comment: No way for any of us to know if what you are doing is illegal or not, which is why you won't get many answers, that was my point.

Comment: Right. By that thinking, though, any of the questions on superuser.com could be used for nefarious purposes. All one has to do is to say: "I'd help you, but I don't know that by helping you ______ (eg. figure out how to enable a newsreader in Emacs) how do I know you're not using that to download/view child pornography?" It's difficult to judge morality. And that's /my/ point.

Comment: "It's difficult to judge morality" for some people it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered several tools for this:

1. [ISORecorder](http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/isorecorder.htm): This is a great tool for a straight clone of the disc. Some discs are uncooperative though.
2. [DVDShrink](http://dvdshrink.org/): This program runs your DVD through adjustable amount of compression so it can fit on an ISO of a predetermined size. This is a great program; you can still get as good of a picture quality as (1) just by adjusting the compression ratio. The only reason why I would prefer ISORecorder is because it's simpler (but not by much).
3. [DVDDecrypter](http://www.dvddecrypter.org.uk/)
4. [AnyDVD](http://www.slysoft.com/en/anydvd.html)